# WSO2 IS - Active Directory Login - Not working

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

we are trying to connect wso2 Identity server using ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager as primary store ,when the server running we couldn't login to console with AD user or with super tenant user and we get

**Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again.**

in log file i found PRE_AUTHENTICATION error :

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:31:00,537]  INFO 
{org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : 
https://localhost:9443/carbon/ 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,843] DEBUG 
{org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching 
for user AdminSOA 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,843] DEBUG 
{org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using 
default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : 
CN=Users,DC=devdc,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,844] DEBUG 
{org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after 
escaping special characters in AdminSOA : AdminSOA 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,844] DEBUG 
{org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using 
default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : 
CN=Users,DC=devdc,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,844] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: AdminSOA exist: true 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,845] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user AdminSOA 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,845] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : CN=Users,DC=devdc,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,845] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in AdminSOA : AdminSOA 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,845] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : CN=Users,DC=devdc,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,845] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: AdminSOA exist: true 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,846] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-03 01:38:06,847] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION
```

my user-mgt.xml file here

[user-mgt.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SLNWOJo12W1YHIJpO4-H5ZhyfIv4JD4Z)

All Log file here

[Log file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E8ZywwSdyiJ6Hz2RXEAbRauLi8GPz9KG)

thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

As per the error log main cause of the login failure is the following.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find suitable mapped attribute for local claim http://wso2.org/claims/userid
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.DefaultClaimMetadataStore.getMappedAttribute(DefaultClaimMetadataStore.java:360)
```

It seems that claim mapping is not properly configured for the userid claim in ActiveDirectoryUserstoreManager.

Please confirm whether a valid AD attribute is mapped to userid claim in claim configuration section in management console. Refer [1] for more information.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Active+Directory+User+Stores+for+Inbound+Provisioning

Comment: No sir it's not mapped, but how can i map them if i can't enter to the admin console?, i used fresh WSO2 IS and i changed the primary store to AD so i can't enter to WSO2 Admin console, is there any way to enter to console and map them

Comment: can you try with "SCIMEnabled" property set to false in your user-mgt.xml file?